# JavaFX access ui-elements from Controller(Singleton)

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I have a **javafx design** in the file **javafx.fxml** where the root element has the following attribute

`fx:controller="de.roth.jsona.javafx.ViewManagerFX"`

This controller class has a singleton machanism and is binded with some ui-elements.

```
public class ViewManagerFX {

    private static ViewManagerFX instance = new ViewManagerFX();

    @FXML
    private Slider volumeSlider;
    @FXML
    private Label volumeLabel;
    public IntegerProperty volumeValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    @FXML
    private TabPane musicTabs;
    public List<StringProperty> tabNames = new ArrayList<StringProperty>();

    public static ViewManagerFX getInstance() {
        return (instance);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        // Volume
        volumeSlider.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(volumeValue);
        volumeLabel.textProperty().bindBidirectional(volumeValue, new Format() {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                    FieldPosition pos) {
                toAppendTo.append(obj);
                toAppendTo.append("%");
                return toAppendTo;
            }

            @Override
            public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
                return null; // no need to be implemented
            }
        });
        volumeValue.set(Config.getInstance().VOLUME);
    }

    public void addMusicFolderTab(final String t, final ArrayList<MusicListItem> items) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Tab m = new Tab("Test Tab");
                musicTabs.getTabs().add(0, m);              
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The method `addMusicFolderTab` is called from a `thread` that is used to scan files and directories.

In the initialize method I can access the ui-elements but in the method `addMusicFolderTab`, that is called from the filescanner-thread, the variable `musicTabs` is `null`. Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.roth.jsona.javafx.ViewManagerFX$3.run(ViewManagerFX.java:110)
```

I have no clue, why I can't access the TabPane from outside the initialize method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the many questionable patterns used here, the problem is that your `ViewManagerFX` singleton (besides not being a singleton) never has its instance set.

When using FXML, the Controller is created and loaded dynamically by Reflection from the `FXMLoader`.

What happens is that by calling `ViewManagerFX.getInstance()`, you access the a different controller than the one created by the `FXMLoader`. The instance you access is the one created here:

```
private static ViewManagerFX instance = new ViewManagerFX();
```

The quickest way to solve the issue is to set the instance in the `initialize()` since it's called by the `FXMLoader` on the instance created by the `FXMLoader`.

```
public void initialize() {
    instance = this;
    // Volume
    ...
}
```